# Why does the screen width increase on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a problem on mobile devices, my website looks good, but when you scroll down, the screen remains the same but the navigation bar extends to the right. The content of the web remains the same, but a space opens to the right, you can scroll to the right, which has no content, this part is without content. And when I scroll up, there is a very long navigation bar to the right.
I leave my code. And forgive the form of expression but I use a translator to write.
Missing adding styles, but these are the important ones
Thank you !

```css
/* ==== Google font ==== */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:400,600,700');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#logo {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: -0.6em 0;
}
#contact {
  height: 150px;
}
html nav.navbar.navbar-custom {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 38px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 28px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 24px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 20px;
}
h1, h2, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #111;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #008000 !important;
}
h1.h-xlight, h2.h-xlight, h3.h-xlight, h4.h-xlight, h5.h-xlight, h6.h-xlight {
 font-weight: 200;
}
h1.h-light, h2.h-light, h3.h-light, h4.h-light, h5.h-light, h6.h-light {
 font-weight: 300;
}
h1.h-bold, h2.h-bold, h3.h-bold, h4.h-bold, h5.h-bold, h6.h-bold {
 font-weight: 600;
}
h1.font-light, h2.font-light, h3.font-light, h4.font-light, h5.font-light, h6.font-light {
 color: #fff;
}
.big-heading {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
p {
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.text-center {
 font-size: 20px;
}
.service-desc p {
 font-size: 16px;
}
p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}
.highlight-light {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #111;
}
.highlight-dark {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
.highlight-color {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  color: #666;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
}
blockquote {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}
blockquote.bg-light {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  padding: 20px;
  color: #222;
}
blockquote.bg-dark {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  padding: 20px;
}
blockquote strong {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.light {
 font-weight: 400;
}
.site-logo {
 display: flex;
}
.site-logo a.brand {
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#navigation {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
div#navigation-sticky-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 121;
}
.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-brand:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #444;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 21px;
  border-top: none;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}
.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover, .navbar-custom .nav li a:focus, .navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover, .navbar-custom .nav li a:focus, .navbar-custom .nav li.active {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-toggle:active {
 outline: 0;
}
hr {
 margin-top: 10px;
}
hr.bold {
 border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}
.divider-header {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.divider-short {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.marginbot-0 {
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.marginbot-10 {
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
.marginbot-20 {
 margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
.marginbot-30 {
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}
.marginbot-40 {
 margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}
.marginbot-50 {
 margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}
.marginbot-60 {
 margin-bottom: 60px !important;
}
.marginbot-70 {
 margin-bottom: 70px !important;
}
.marginbot-80 {
 margin-bottom: 80px !important;
}
.marginbot-90 {
 margin-bottom: 90px !important;
}
.marginbot-100 {
 margin-bottom: 100px !important;
}
.margintop-0 {
 margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.margintop-10 {
 margin-top: 10px !important;
}
.margintop-20 {
 margin-top: 20px !important;
}
.margintop-30 {
 margin-top: 30px !important;
}
.margintop-40 {
 margin-top: 40px !important;
}
.margintop-45 {
 margin-top: 45px !important;
}
.margintop-50 {
 margin-top: 50px !important;
}
#container-2 {
 background-color: #EBB250;
}
.home-section {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 120;
}
.home-section2 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 120;
}
.inner-section {
  padding-top: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}
.home-section.nopadd-bot {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.section-heading h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.section-heading p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
.color-dark .section-heading h2 {
 color: #111;
}
.color-dark .section-heading p {
 color: #444;
}
.color-dark .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-dark .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .section-heading h2 {
 color: #fff;
}
.color-light .section-heading p {
 color: #fefefe;
}
.color-light blockquote, .color-light p {
 color: #fefefe;
}
.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}
.bg-gray {
 background: #f9f9f9;
}
.bg-dark {
 background: #404040;
}
.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}
.hero {
  background: url(../img/jardines/jardin0.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 200px 0 200px 0;
  height: auto;
}
.hero h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  margin: 40px 0 10px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}
.hero h1 span {
  color: #a1a9b0;
 display: inline-block;
}
.hero p {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #fefefe;
}
.learn-more-btn {
 background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 1);
 padding: 20px 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #309383;
 margin: 60px 0 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.learn-more-btn:hover, .learn-more-btn:focus {
 background: rgba(61, 201, 179, 0.6);
 color: #fff;
}
.intro {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
}
.intro-inner {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 padding: 120px 0 20px;
}
.brand-heading {
 font-size: 40px;
}
.intro-text {
 font-size: 18px;
}
.carousel-inner img {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 650px;
}
.carousel-control {
 width: 0;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: none;
}
.carousel-control.left span {
 padding: 0;
}
.carousel-control.right span {
 padding: 0;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 z-index: 5;
 display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .icon-prev {
 left: 30px;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-next {
 right: 30px;
}
.carousel-control.left span:hover, .carousel-control.right span:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.header-text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 1.8%;
 right: auto;
 width: 96.66666666666666%;
 color: #fff;
}
.header-text h2 {
 font-size: 40px;
}
.header-text h2 span {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header-text h3 span {
 color: #fff;
}
.btn-min-block {
 min-width: 170px;
 line-height: 26px;
}
.btn-theme {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
.btn-theme:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: #fff;
}
.service-box {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
 padding: 40px 20px;
}
.service-box:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -20px;
}
.service-icon {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.service-desc h5 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service-desc .divider-header {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.item {
 margin: 10px;
}
.item img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#contact {
 background-color: #C9E4E4;
}
.form-group {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn-lg, .btn-group-lg > .btn {
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.input-group-addon {
 background-color: #fefefe;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}
.boxcol-25 {
 width: 100%;
}
.box-social {
 list-style: none;
}
.sidebar .widget h5 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .widget {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.widget ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li a {
 color: #666;
}
.widget.widget_categories ul li:before {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: "\e684";
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li figure {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li h6 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li span {
 font-size: 14px;
}
.widget .tagcloud a {
 padding: 4px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.widget .tagcloud a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #333;
}
footer {
 background-image: url(http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg);
 background-position: center bottom;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 min-height: 50vh;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 40px 0 30px;
}
footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 16px;
}
footer a.totop {
 color: #fff;
}
footer a.totop:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
.share-button {
 padding-top: 50px !important;
}
ul.footer-menu {
 list-style: none;
}
ul.footer-menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
ul.footer-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
 line-height: 1.1em;
}
ul.footer-menu li:first-child a {
 border-left: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.social-widget {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.social-widget ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
footer .social-widget ul.team-social li a {
 margin: 0 5px;
}
.testimonialslide {
 margin-top: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
}
.testimonialslide ul li blockquote {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: none;
}
.testimonialslide ul li h4 {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.testimonialslide ul li h4 span {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.btn {
 border-radius: 2px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 14px;
}
.btn.btn-noradius {
 border-radius: 0;
}
a.btn:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
.btn-red {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #c83539;
 border-color: #c83539;
}
.btn-red:hover, .btn-red:focus, .btn-red:active, .btn-red.active {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #666;
 border-color: #666;
}
.btn-red:active {
 background-image: none;
}
.btn-skin:hover, .btn-skin:focus, .btn-skin:active, .btn-skin.active {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #666;
 border-color: #666;
}
.btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {
 border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
 outline: 0;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #28c3ab;
}
.btn-huge {
 padding: 25px;
 font-size: 26px;
}
.banner-social-buttons {
 margin-top: 0;
}
.progress {
 height: 40px;
}
.progress-bar {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
 .navbar {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
 }
 .top-nav-collapse {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
 }
 .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
 }
 .intro {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .brand-heading {
  font-size: 100px;
 }
 .intro-text {
  font-size: 25px;
 }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
 #navigation {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 .site-logo {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  float: none;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  color: #eee;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
 }
 .navbar-header {
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .navbar-header button {
  background: #111;
 }
 .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .navbar-custom .nav {
  background: #444;
 }
 .service-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 .team-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 form#contact-form {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 .xs-marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }
 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}
.navbar .navbar-custom {
 padding: 0;
}
.makina img {
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 bottom: 120px;
}
.makina-2 img {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Principal</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai|Cormorant+Upright|Farsan" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
<section class="hero" id="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right navicon"> <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#"> <span></span> </a> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center inner">
                <div class="animatedParent">
                    <h1 class="animated fadeInDown">Se</h1>
                    <p class="animated fadeInUp">De</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div id="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="site-logo"> <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" /> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"> <a href="#intro">Casa</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#about">Sobre mi</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="#service">Servicios</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
    <div class="container marginbot-50">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="animatedParent">
                    <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
                        <h2 class="h-bold">hola</h2>
                        <div class="divider-header"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 animatedParent">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <p>Aqui v acontenido que n ahora no viene </p>
                    <p>Especialistas</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin btn-scroll">Mas servicios</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="service" class="home-section color-dark bg-gray">
    <div class="container marginbot-50">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div>
                    <div class="section-heading text-center">
                        <h2 class="h-bold">¿Què hacemos?</h2>
                        <div class="divider-header"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row animatedParent">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
                        <div class="service-box"> <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg">
                            <div class="service-desc">
                                <p>texto ejemplo</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nue</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
                        <div class="service-box">
                            <div class="service-desc"> <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg">
                                <p>Ejemplo.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nu</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="animated rotateInDownRight slow">
                        <div class="service-box">
                            <div class="service-desc"> <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg">
                                <p>Tod</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nu</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="animated rotateInDownRight slower">
                        <div class="service-box">
                            <div class="service-desc"> <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg">
                                <p>Ven</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nu</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="works" class="home-section color-dark text-center bg-white">
    <div class="container marginbot-50">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div>
                    <div class="animatedParent">
                        <div class="section-heading text-center">
                            <h2 class="h-bold animated bounceInDown">Al</h2>
                            <div class="divider-header"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row animatedParent">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="row gallery-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp"> <a href="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg" title="Vea como queda tras pasar nosotros..." data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg"> <img src="#" class="img-responsive" alt="img"> </a> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp slow"> <a href="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg" title="Remondes y podas eficaces..." data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg"> <img src="#" class="img-responsive" alt="img"> </a> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp slower"> <a href="http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg" title="Diseñamos su jardin..." data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg"> <img src="#" class="img-responsive" alt="img"> </a> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp"> <a href=" http://i46.tinypic.com/2n0vdw0.jpg" title="Aramos su huerto y olivar..." data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg"> <img src="#" class="img-responsive" alt="img"> </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer> </footer>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post a **minimal** code example!

Comment: why is this tagged with `bootstrap-4` if you aren't using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I write this code because I think it would be necessary to find the error. And I put Bootstrapt-4 because it came out by default, I wanted to add bootstrap.                                                                                                  I just want to offer the best so they can help me.    
Thanks for your support